# Is it possible in Ubuntu 22.04 to have one app/window show/present in several "desktops" simultaneously -- like in 20.04?

Tags: workspaces, multiple-desktops

In 20.04, if you have an application open and right-click on its title bar, you are presented with a list of possible actions. They include actions local to this desktop/workspace, like "*Always on top*", and actions to manipulate desktops/workspaces location of this app/window - like "*Move to workspace left*".
Much of that can be done after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04, even if such actions are invoked very differently. However, I have not found a way to get a app/window to show in all desktops/workspaces simultaneously ("*Always on visible workspace*").

*Possibly related*: Right-clicking on the top bar of an app/window show nothing (no possible actions).

*Possibly related*: There is now a tab on the top bar for some app related actions; it used to be possible to attach such to the app's main window, but apparently no more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can in Ubuntu 22.04. I pressed the Menu key (mine had a Windows logo because my machine came with Windows pre-installed) to show all my apps. It could be the Escape key on your machine, check your system shortcuts (dconf-editor or GNOME settings).

Comment: Well, yes, this shows small icons representing every workspace. It does not allow me to have **the same app** showing in **all workspaces** - like, so that when I switch through my workspaces that specific app is always on the screen...

Which is what I could do in 20.4 and am trying to recreate or recover.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a **window** to always be **on top** of other apps? You can right click the window header and select the "always on top" option (this only works if the app is windowed).

Comment: Yep, it did in 20.4.  I then upgraded to 2.04 and I have a rather crippled UI, with the new horizontal selection of workspaces/desktops, and no option in the top bar of app windows (except to minimize to show only the title bar, and the remove the window from the screen).

I have another machine which survived 20.4 --> 22.4 without troubles; so something must have been botched by the upgrade of this one.  But I have no idea what. Both machines worked the same (proper) way in 20.4.

Comment: Oh, so I guess you can just reinstall GNOME (by purging, auto-removing and installing it again). Most of the times I had an issue with something I solved with purging and installing. Try it and see if it solves your problem.